# How can i make a container with these contents

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

***Container Image:***
[image]

I want to know how I can construct this container and add the contents. I tried a **ListTile** it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one

[image]

```
Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
          height: 120,
          width: 400,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: (Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Yelena Stevens",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 3,
                        ),
                        Text("Star Rating Widget")
                      ],
                    ),
                    Text("Feb 23, 2021")
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 6),
                Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.")
              ],
            )),
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

A ListTile is just a Widget.

Why not build your own?

Something like:

```
class MyTile extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Text("Yelena Stevens", textAlign: TextAlign.start),
      Text("Feb 23", textAlign: TextAlign.end),
      StarDisplayWidget(),
      Text("Lorum ipsum...")
    ]);
  }
}
```